# What is chance performance cut-off for a 2-part dichotomous response?

Tags: binomial-distribution

If subjects had to give 2-alternative forced choice responses for a task (Y/N) and then rate the certainty of their response (also 2-alternative forced choice: High/Low), and we analyzed their responses in the 4 resulting bins (Y-Hi, Y-Lo, N-Hi, N-Lo), what would be considered "chance performance" -- less than 50% or 25%?

Answer (score 1):

There's no single right answer here because one could posit several different models of how a subject who's terrible at the task would behave. For example, perhaps such a subject would randomly choose between Y-Lo and N-Lo with equal probability (they never have high confidence), or perhaps they would choose among all four options with equal probability, or perhaps they would be more likely to choose low confidence than high confidence, and so on.

A larger, related concern is that the idea of chance performance is often applied rather naively. For example, if 10% of a people in a certain population have depression, and a depression test works by simply declaring that every examinee doesn't have depression, the test will be 90% accurate, which is well above 50%, so we should expect any good test to be more accurate than 90%, not more accurate than 50%.

At any rate, I'm guessing that what you really want to do is figure out how accurate subjects were. There are a number of ways to do this, but as I think the argument in my first paragraph shows, simply showing that the subjects do *not* behave according to a certain null model isn't a good strategy.